# from string to numeric variables

Tags: stata

I am new to Stata and I am having trouble transforming a string variable (country codes) to a numeric variable. The documentation gives the following command:

```
encode cntry, gen(cntrynum)
```

However, when I use it I do not get a number per category but a number per row. So, the same country that appears thousands of times with its code gets thousands of numeric values assigned to it:

`| cntry[1]   | US   | | cntry[2]   | US   | | cntry[3]   | US   | | cntry[4]   | GB   |` 
...

How do I get one number per category, regardless of how many times it appears in the dataset?

`| cntry[1]   | US   | | cntry[1]   | US   | | cntry[1]   | US   | | cntry[2]   | GB   |` 
...

Comment: -encode- should be exactly what you want. Check for leading or trailing spaces in the string variable.